# No me guarda el valor del sharedpreference en la otra actividad, ¿como verificar que el sharedpreference tiene un valor o existe?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences

'''
ingreso un valor en en mainactivity y lo envió a la siguiente actividad , minimizo la app y la cierro desde multitarea pero no me mantiene ese valor y se abre desde el activity inicial ,¿cómo enviar el dato desde el mainactivity a la segundaactivity y al minimizar la app y cerrarla desde multitarea , al abrirla de nuevo se abra en la segundaactivity y mantenga en valor ingresado?
'''
este es el MainActiviti
'''
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var sharedPreferences:SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var txtnombre=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txtnombre)
    var btningresar=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnIngresar)

    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("SHARED",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    btningresar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        var nombre:String=txtnombre.text.toString()

        val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putString("NOMBRE",nombre)
        editor.apply()

        val intent=Intent(this,SegundaActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    })
}
```

}
'''
este es el segundo activity
'''
class SegundaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var preferences:SharedPreferences
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda)

    var btnsalir=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnsalir)
    preferences=getSharedPreferences("SHARED",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=preferences.edit()
    val nombre=preferences.getString("NOMBRE","")
    tvnombre.text=nombre

    btnsalir.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=preferences.edit()
        editor.clear()
        editor.apply()

        val intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No te guarda el valor puesto que al cargar la segunda Activity no estas guardando el valor, debes usar el metodo `.apply()` :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var txtnombre=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txtnombre)
    var btningresar=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnIngresar)
   

    btningresar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        var nombre:String=txtnombre.text.toString()

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("SHARED",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putString("NOMBRE",nombre)
      
        //Guarda valor en preferencia.
        editor.apply()
    

        val intent=Intent(this,SegundaActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    })
}
```

Comment: Si esta , pero no me guarda , cierro la app desde multitarea y me vuelve a iniciar desde el mainActivity , Cual es el error ? en la segunda actividad también esta val preferences que es un sharedpreference

Comment: En tu codigo no esta en MainActivity, esa es la primera Activity y debes guardar el valor

Comment: ya lo puse en el códido , pero me sigue sin guardarlo

Answer (score 0):

Si cierras la app desde la multitarea al abrir nuevamente la app se lanzará la actividad `MainActivity`, para evitar eso compruebas si hay algún valor guardado y lanzas `SegundaActivity`
MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate (savedIntanceState: Bundle?){
    ...
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val nombre = sharedPreferences.getString("NOMBRE", null)
    if (nombre != null){
        val intent = Intent(this, SegundaActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
    ...
}
```